# Why my CNN returns always the same result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to build a CNN that classify object in 3 main classes.The three objects consist of a lamborghini , cylinder head and a piece of plane. My data set consists of 6580 images , almost 2200 image for each class.You can see my dataset on google drive [dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8RIItT88GXJcUxaZWNrd29wLVE?usp=sharing).
The architecture of my CNN is AlexNet , but I've modified the output of fully connected layer 8 from 1000 to 3.
I have used these settings for training

```
test_iter:1000
test_interval:1000
base_lr:0.001
lr_policy:"step"
gamma:0.1
stepsize:2500
max_iter:40000
momentum:0.9
weight_decay:0.0005
```

But , the problem is when I deploy my model after training the result is always the following `{'prob': array([[ 0.33333334,  0.33333334,  0.33333334]], dtype=float32)}`.

the code below , is my script to load the model and output the vector of probabilities.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import caffe
import cv2

MODEL_FILE ='deploy_ex0.prototxt'
PRETRAINED='snapshot_ex0_1_model_iter_40000.caffemodel'

caffe.set_mode_cpu()
net = caffe.Net(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED, caffe.TEST)

#preprocessing 

transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})

#mean substraction 

mean_file = np.array([104,117,123]) 
transformer.set_mean('data', mean_file)

transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)

#batch size 
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1,3,227,227)

#load image in data layer 

im=cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img =cv2.resize(im, (227,227))

net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', img)

#compute 

out=net.forward()

print out
```

I am wondering why I have a result like this ? would you help me to debug my CNN ?

Also, after training I got these results

```
I0421 06:56:12.285953  2224 solver.cpp:317] Iteration 40000, loss = 5.06557e-05
I0421 06:56:12.286027  2224 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 40000, Testing net (#0)
I0421 06:58:32.159469  2224 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.99898
I0421 06:58:32.159626  2224 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.00183688 (* 1 = 0.00183688 loss)
I0421 06:58:32.159643  2224 solver.cpp:322] Optimization Done.
I0421 06:58:32.159654  2224 caffe.cpp:222] Optimization Done.
```

Thank you

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER OF 11 MAY :**

I used a simple model 1 conv , 1 reul , 1 pool and 2 fully connected layers.. The code below is the architecture specification :

```
name:"CNN"
layer {
  name: "convnet"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror:true
    crop_size:227
    mean_value:87.6231
    mean_value:87.6757

    mean_value:87.1677
    #mean_file:"/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

layer {
  name: "convnet"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror:true
    crop_size:227
    mean_value:87.6231
    mean_value:87.6757

    mean_value:87.1677
    #mean_file:"/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 20
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}

layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 300
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer 
{
   name:"ip2"
   type:"InnerProduct"
   bottom:"ip1"
   top:"ip2"
   param
   {
    lr_mult:1
   }
   param
   {
    lr_mult:2
   }
   inner_product_param 
   {
    num_output: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
        }
   }

}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

I trained this CNN for 22 epochs and I got accuracy 86 %. For the solver parameters I used :

```
net: "/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/simple_model/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 50
test_interval: 100
base_lr: 0.00001
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
display: 100
max_iter: 3500
snapshot: 100
snapshot_prefix: "/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/simple_model/snap_shot_model"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Now , when I deploy the model it does not return the same vector of probabilities. But , there is one issue , is when I loaded the model and I tested it on validation_lmdb folder , I did not get the same accuracy value , I got almost 56% .

I used the script below to calculate the accuracy :

```
import os
import glob
#import cv2
import caffe
import lmdb
import numpy as np
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2

MODEL_FILE ='deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED='snap_shot_model_iter_3500.caffemodel'

caffe.set_mode_cpu()
#load_model

net = caffe.Net(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED, caffe.TEST)

#load input and configure preprocessing



#mean_file = np.array([104,117,123])

transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
#transformer.set_mean('data', mean_file)
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)


#fixing the batch size

net.blobs['data'].reshape(1,3,227,227)

lmdb_env=lmdb.open('/home/jaba/caffe/data/diota_model/val1_lmdb')

lmdb_txn=lmdb_env.begin()

lmdb_cursor=lmdb_txn.cursor()

datum=caffe_pb2.Datum()


correct_predictions=0

for key,value in lmdb_cursor:

    datum.ParseFromString(value)

    label=datum.label
    data=caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)

    image=np.transpose(data,(1,2,0))


    net.blobs['data'].data[...]=transformer.preprocess('data',image)

    out=net.forward()
    out_put=out['prob'].argmax()
    if label==out_put:
    correct_predictions=correct_predictions+1



print 'accuracy :'
print correct_predictions/1002.0
```

I changed the size of the data set 1002 for testing and 4998 for learning .
Would you give me some suggestions to solve the issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: I dearly hope that's a typo: a learning rate of 1000 is ridiculous.  :-)

Comment: What is the model's batch size?  Also, please post a few samples of the input data, or describe the differences among your classes; we're not going to crawl through 4600 photos to see what class 2 looks like.

Comment: What is your test images class distribution? Small loss is saying it has learned something.

Comment: You may check mean_file = np.array([104,117,123])

Comment: when image loaded with opencv image loaded BGR so try caffe.io.load_image and look results if solves when using opencv change the channel order

Comment: @Prune Sorry for not giving more details. I 've corrected the learning rate and the batch size is 256 for  training and 50 for test. My data consists of 3 different objects (a lamborghini , cylinder head and a piece of a plane ). I have used 85 % of my data set for training and 15 % for testing

Comment: @salehinejad I have used those values for training as mean value . What should I do in this case ?

Comment: @user7417788 I understand its the mean; shouldn't it be extracted from data rather than hardcoded?

Comment: @salehinejad In fact when I 've used the mean from data but the training of the network failed . So , I tried the mean values and the training of the network  succeded . I will try to run training another time using mean value from my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see two distinct problems, different forms of over-fitting.  WIth 85% of your 6580 images for training, you have 5593 in training, 987 in testing.

**ONE**

40000 iterations * (256 images/iteration) * (1 epoch/5593 images) ~= 1831 epochs.
On the ILSVRC data set (1.28M images), AlexNet trains for only 40-50 epochs (depending on scale-out).
Your model finished with a loss of effectively 0 and got only 1 photo wrong in the entire testing set.

**TWO**

AlexNet's widths (filters per layer) are tuned for the 1000 classes and myriad features of the ILSVRC data set.  You haven't scaled it down for your data.  Layer 5 broadens to 4096 filters: that's nearly one for each image.  Where ILSVRC trains Alexnet to recognize features such as a feline face, one side of a wheeled vehicle, etc. -- your model will train to recognize a dark blue Lambourghini from an angle of 30 degrees off front, 8 degrees above horizontal, with grass in the background and a poplar tree in the background on the driver's side.

In other words, your trained AlexNet fits the training data set like a pour-on plastic shell.  It's not going to fit *anything* except the initial data set.

I'm mildly surprised that it doesn't do a *little* better on other autos, other cylinder heads, and plane pieces.  However, I've seen enough over-fitted models that had effectively random output.

---

First, reduce the length of training.  Second, try reducing the **num_output** size of each layer.

---

**EDIT AFTER OP's COMMENTS 11 MAY**

Yes, you have to reduce the number of kernels/filters/outputs in each layer.  Layer 5, in particular, has 4K filters, which means that the network can allocate almost 1 filter per photo in your data set.  This does not make for effective learning: instead of having a handful of filters that learn features of gaskets, you have over 1000 filters, each learning one very specific feature of a particular gasket photo.

AlexNet, GoogleNet, ResNet, VGG, et alia were all built and tuned for a problem of general discrimination of still images over a wide variety of objects.  You can certainly use the general concepts, but they are *not* good topologies to use for a problem that is so much smaller and better defined.

Comment: I have done the following thins. I reduced the dataset to 6000 images (5000 for training and 1000 for testing ). Also, I changed num_ouput of fully connected layer 6 and fully connected layer 7 to 1000. I have changed also the solver.prototxt

Comment: You haven't fully described the changes, but this is a start.  You still have to attack the internal problem of kernel bandwidth in the inner layers (problem **TWO** above).  You're still trying to solve a small problem with a large topology.

Comment: Sorry for not describing the hole thing . In fact , I reduced the dataset to 6000  (5000 for training and 1000 for testing )
Also, I changed num_ouput of FC6 , FC7 to 1000, batch_size from to 50, solver(test_iter:100;test_interval:500;max_iter:4000)  .
I got accuracy 92% , the problem is when I try to deploy the model  I have got the following error : Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc8'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 2 1000 (2000); target param shape is 3 1000 (3000). To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer

Comment: (1) Please edit the salient information into the original question; (2) The deployment error may be a separate problem -- did you ever try deploying the original (non-working) model?; (3) So now you're training for only 1 epoch??

Comment: (2) I tried to deploy the original model but it always return the same vector of probabilities (3) for the second model I have trained for 40 epochs

Comment: (2) Thanks; I wanted to know whether deployment worked at all for you.  (3) Right; sorry.  I read the number from **test_iter** instead of **max_iter**.

Comment: for question (2) I meant that the deployment succeeded but the output is always wrong ( same of output vector of probability for any image example ) . For problem TWO, I think I misunderstood you . Should I reduce the num_output of conv layers ? two more question is the use of (a modified) alexnet architecture and training it  from scratch is  bad for my use case ? should I use a shallow architecture of CNN ? Does the use of a Convnet as feature extractor is a good idea for my case ? Thanks and sorry for my dumb questions

Comment: You should edit these last few details into your original question: they help focus.  I'm adding to my answer.

Comment: I have changed the architecture to a simple  one  . I deployed the new model  . This time , I have no more the issue of returning the same vector of probabilities .